# start managed web logic server in ssl

Tags: oracle11g, weblogic, weblogic12c

This is with regards to Oracle web logic server 12c.

I have deployed trusted SSL certificates and configure custom identity and trust stores on both admin and managed server.

I was asked to start both of these servers in SSL mode (https) only as these servers were attacked by hackers. For regular login (http), I am using `./startWebLogic.sh` to start admin server and `./start ManagedWebLogic.sh <managed server name> http://adminservername:portnumber` to start managed server.

How can I start these servers in **https/ssl mode only**?

Comment: WebLogic Server does not have a "ssl mode" as you say. It has the capacity to handle ssl connections from ssl clients. For that, you have to insert your key and certificate in keystores, configure keystores in the domain configuration and enable the SSL listen port on each server (7002 as default) Take a look at this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/SECMG/ssl_overview.htm#SECMG718) for details.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Thanks for your response. I have configured keystores and ssl is enabled. I am able to access deployed application in both non http and https ports. But I want the server to start only in HTTPS, not http. Basically I want to disable HTTP port on server

Comment: So, you "just" have to disable the standard listen port (ie 7001) for each server in your domain. Can be done via the admin console.

Comment: I disabled 7001 and enabled only 7002 and tried restarting admin server. I could not start the server as it was unable to find port no. Something related to config.xml I believe

Comment: can you post the error message from the log file ?

Comment: I am not able to find error message. Let me check again.

Also, I have one more issue. I suspect because of this issue, I am unable to bring admin server up. We have ssl certificate for "*.somedomainname.com" and this certificate was deployed on "xyz.somedomainname.com". Error log showing system is unable to match ssl certificate with the server name. How to resolve this? I think I will be able to start server if I could resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Disabled non SSL port/HTTPS port and enabled SSL port on both administration server and managed servers